# Run site-level workflow programmatically

Tags: workflow

I have created a site-level workflow and now I need to run it from some code. For test purpose I wrote event receiver:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            SPWorkflowManager spWorkflowManager = properties.List.ParentWeb.Site.WorkflowManager;
            SPWorkflowAssociationCollection wfCollection = properties.List.ParentWeb.WorkflowAssociations;
            var wfSite = properties.List.ParentWeb.WorkflowAssociations[0];
            spWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(properties.ListItem, wfSite, "test");
        }
```

My code crashes on `spWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow` :( Where I did mistake?

Comment: Please share the error message you are getting on `spWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow`

Comment: Message have only error code from COM environment.

Answer (score 1):

I find solution. I have 2 mistake:

1. I can't use SPListItem on Site-level WF, I change it to
   SPSite via properties object;
2. I have to add my workflow to
       site via Site Settings.

After I did these 2 think my workflow are run.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this blog
http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2008/01/18/programmatically-start-workflow.aspx

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, but it's doesn't my approach.